# TSQL - How do I use SUM in a virtual COLUMN inside a select?

Tags: t-sql

```
create proc sp_SumVirtual
as
   select a.year, sum(b.PriceDay*b.AmmountDays) profit
   from vehicles a, rent b 
   where a.Matriculation = b.Matriculation 
   GROUP BY a.year
```

Okay so, with this I got the amount of money EACH car has made, but I need the whole amount. So, is there a way I can make SUM from the virtual table Profit? Because that is all I need..or do you suggest another way?

Comment: That tells you how much each year, not how much each car - just sayin'

Comment: This would be easier if that was a udf instead of a proc - is that a possibility? Procs are a pain to manipulate results from inside TSQL

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WITH ROLLUP` on your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    a.year, SUM(b.PriceDay*b.AmmountDays) profit
FROM 
    dbo.vehicles a
INNER JOIN
    dbo.rent b ON a.Matriculation = b.Matriculation 
GROUP BY 
    a.year WITH ROLLUP
```

This will give you an additional row with `NULL` as the value of `year` and the value in the sum column will be the total sum over all grouped rows.

**Update:** so you want to have the sum for each year, but also another column with the total sum over all rows of all years??

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.year, 
    SUM(b.PriceDay*b.AmmountDays) profit,
    (SELECT SUM(b2.PriceDay * b2.AmountDays)  
     FROM dbo.vehicles a2
     INNER JOIN dbo.rent b2 ON a2.Matriculation = b2.Matriculation) AS TotalProfit 
FROM 
    dbo.vehicles a
INNER JOIN
    dbo.rent b ON a.Matriculation = b.Matriculation 
GROUP BY 
    a.year
```

HOWEVER: this will **NOT** be performing very well, since you calculate the `TotalProfit` again and again - for each row that will be output.....

Comment: I got it all messed up since im spanish and i had to delete many things from the proc to make it simpliest..and i could have had some errors there..But what i really need about this proc is to give me a NEW COLUMN with the sum of the profit's rows..THANK YOU VERY MUCH! BTW..

Comment: "sum(b2.PriceDay * b2.AmountDays) over()" instead of the subquery is simpler and should be more effective

Answer (score 0):

```
Select v.year, Sum(r.PriceDay*r.AmmountDays) profit 
From vehicles v Join rent r  
   On r.Matriculation = v.Matriculation  
Group By v.year 
With RollUp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp table along with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT
    a.year, SUM(b.PriceDay*b.AmmountDays) profit
INTO #Temp
FROM
    dbo.vehicles a
INNER JOIN
    dbo.rent b ON a.Matriculation = b.Matriculation
GROUP BY
    a.year

SELECT *
FROM #Temp

UNION ALL

SELECT year, Sum(profit)
FROM #Temp
Group by year
```